# How to create "local" namespace when using WPF with IronPython?

Tags: c#, python, wpf, xaml, ironpython

I'm trying to create a type converter to be used in WPF xaml.  I made sure the equivalent C# code works just fine and then ported it to IronPython.  However, I'm stuck on referring to the TC class in xaml.  More specifically, how to point the "local" namespace to IronPython global namespace?  Below is the code, it's not running because `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:global"` generates error.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("PresentationFramework")
clr.AddReference("PresentationCore")
clr.AddReference("System.Xml")
from System.Xml import XmlReader
from System.IO import StringReader
from System.Windows.Markup import XamlReader
from System.Windows.Data import IValueConverter
from System.Windows import Visibility

class tc(IValueConverter):
    def Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture):
        if value:
            return Visibility.Visible
        else:
            return Visibility.Collapsed

    def ConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, culture):
        pass


s = XmlReader.Create(StringReader('''
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:global"  
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:tc x:Key="tc" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox x:Name="checkbox" IsChecked="True" Content="Visible" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Button Visibility="{Binding ElementName=checkbox, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource tc}}" Content="Button" Height="20" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
'''))


win = XamlReader.Load(s)
win.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. https://www.developerfusion.com/community/blog-entry/8389508/ironpython-and-wpf-part-3-data-binding/  .  Why write absolutely everything in ironpython though? Is your converter going to need to be dynamic? You could write converters in c#.  In this specific instance there is already a converter defined. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for commenting.  I'm not writing an standalone application, but using IronPython to add extensions to another software.  I don't have other choices.  The bool to visibility is just used for demonstration purpose, my actual type converter will be more complicated than that.

Comment: You could either do your translation in an ironpython viewmodel. Or. Use emit to dynamically build a c# dll.